# Gradle 'android' project refresh failed

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I'm new to android, When i updated my android studio version of 2.3.1 and after that when i build my project i have facing following issue

```
Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1.
Searched in the following locations:
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.1/gradle-2.3.1.pom
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.1/gradle-2.3.1.jar
Required by:
project :CordovaLib
```

**build.graddle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
repositories {

    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {

    jcenter()
}
}
```

i have struggling this issue for long time. I read all solution but nothing can solve this issue. Please anyone give solutions for this issue.

Comment: this is project gradle or module gradle?
post both the gradle files.
if it is project gradle then remove the first line `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`

Comment: this is module gradle

Comment: have you tried using new gradle `2.3.3` or 2.3.2?

Comment: yes but stii i got same issue
Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1.
Searched in the following locations:
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.1/gradle-2.3.1.pom
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.1/gradle-2.3.1.jar
Required by:
    project :CordovaLib

Comment: PLease post your project gradle, AFAIK these fields are not defined in module, they are defined in project gradle